# How do I construct a Pin-It button for flickr feed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pinterest

I have a flickr feed on my site, and I'd like to add a Pinterest "Pin-it" button under each image.

Here's the feed script:

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=72157647581330595&nsid=127682596@N07&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
    var large = (item.media.m).replace('_m.jpg', '_b.jpg');

    if(i <= 20){
    $('#list').append('<li class="picture"><a class="slide-img" data-lightbox="engagement" href="' + large + '"><img src="' + large + '"/></a></li>');

    }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

I want to add the

```
<a href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pushpinevents.com&media=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm4.staticflickr.com%2F3838%2F15273469932_0c3ceaeb96_b.jpg&description=%40PushPin%20Events" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="beside"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_20.png" /></a>
```

code to the `.append` method and replace the url string with the image link.

My best guess is that I need to define a variable from the flickr URL and replace the '/' with %3F ':' with %2A and the like.

So something like:

```
var link = (large).replace('/', '%3F');
```

**Question 1 - How can I replace multiple characters in one `.replace` method?**

After that's defined, my next swing at the code would look like:

```
<script>
        $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=72157647581330595&nsid=127682596@N07&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
        var large = (item.media.m).replace('_m.jpg', '_b.jpg');

        if(i <= 20){
        $('#list').append('<li class="picture"><a class="slide-img" data-lightbox="engagement" href="' + large + '"><img src="' + large + '"/></a></li><br><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pushpinevents.com&media='+link+'" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="beside">Pin It!</a>');

        }
        });
        });
        </script>
```

**Question 2 - Is this the most efficient way to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(large);` which did the trick.

That left me with

```
$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=72157647581330595&nsid=127682596@N07&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
    var large = (item.media.m).replace('_m.jpg', '_b.jpg');
    var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(large);
    console.log(encodedUrl);


    if(i <= 20){


    }$('#list').append('<li class="picture"><span class="round"><a data-lightbox="engagement" href="' + large + '"><img src="' + large + '"/></a><br><a class="pinit round" target="_blank" href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pushpinevents.com&media='+encodedUrl+'&description=%40PushPin%20Events" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="beside"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i> Pin it</a></span></li>');
    });
    });
```

Cheers!